# How to discard float precision in Ruby

Tags: ruby, floating-point

I want to discard float precision.

```
(4.43597).discard(3)   =>   4.435 (not 4.436)
```

I don't want to use round. 
How should I do it ?
I can't find of a way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. multiply by 1000
2. cast to int
3. divide by 1000.0

Comment: Tiny tweak: I think you need to cast back to a float before multiplying by 1000.

Comment: Why? Or do you mean, I should cast back to float before *dividing*?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, apologies!

Comment: @Ben: That's not necessary, because the result of `int * float` is `float`. That's the reason for telling the OP to divide by `1000.0`, note the `.0` at the end, which makes that a `double` or `float` (I don't know Ruby, so I don't know, which type is the default).

Comment: Thanks, I'm a Ruby newb, and hadn't taken the `.0` into account (if you don't use it, of course it thinks it's still dealing with an integer, hence my having to cast). Thanks for the clarification (I must learn to read properly!)

Comment: @Ben: Well, it *is* easily overlooked :-)

Answer (score 3):

Still use `round`, but have the effect of truncating at the desired position.

```
(4.43597-0.0005).round(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit overkill, but nonetheless,

```
>> (4.43597).to_s.scan(/\d+\.\d{3}/)[0].to_f
=> 4.435
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:
1. multiply by 1000
2. use floor() to round down
3. divide by 1000.0